# Accented data gets corrupted

Tags: python

I have a file with German accented characters that I am processing with a Python program. When, for example, I open the file with Notebook it displays correctly, such as “Übersetzt”.When, however, I print such terms, they are corrupted to “Ãœbersetzt”. Where is this code page change occurring and how can I rectify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible reasons:

1. file encoding - python3 assumes `utf-8` so if your file uses other encoding glitches might appear.
2. your terminal is unable to output `Ü`.

It is easier to check 2., just do

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.lookup('LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS'))
```

If it output `Ü` that means your terminal is able to output it and you should find what encoding is used in file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the encoding='utf-8' option

open('d:\aatemp\C814LogicClass.htm', encoding='utf-8')